# Custom Formula to Concatenate Multiple Rows If Condition Met

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I'm having trouble writing a UDF for Sheets that would allow me to concatenate multiple rows of data into a single text field with a delimiter based on unique ID. I've seen examples of this for excel, but haven't been able to find a sheet's equivalent. Basically, I want to concatenate all values in B:B where B(i) = A(i) delimited by a comma or pipe or some other delimiter.

Basically, I want to concatenate all values in B:B where B(i) = A(i) in a single cell delimited by a comma or pipe or some other delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

See if this formula helps

```
=textjoin(", ", 1, unique(filter(B:B, B:B=C:C)))
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=textjoin(", "; 1; unique(filter(B:B; B:B=C:C)))
```

If that doesn't help, please share a copy of your spreadsheet with editing rights.

Answer (score 0):

> to concatenate all values in B:B where B(i) = A(i) in a single cell delimited by a comma

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))&",", 
 QUERY(B:B, "select count(B) where B matches '"&
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A)&"' group by B label count(B)''", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

and to remove commas from the end you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REPT(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))&",", 
 QUERY(B:B, "select count(B) where B matches '"&
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A)&"' group by B label count(B)''", 0)), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]